# Could using a condition like `std::cin.peek() != '\n'` to catch `cin` extraneous input be a good thing to do?

Tags: c++

I'm using the behavior of `std::cin` leaving the extraneous input inside the buffer until they are called again. Could that be a bad practice?

Example code -

```cpp
double getDoubleInput()
{
    double x{};
    std::cin >> x;
    assert("Syntax Error!!" && !std::cin.fail());
    return x;
}

char getOperatorInput()
{
    char x{};
    std::cin >> x;
    bool b{x == '+' || x == '-' || x == '*' || x == '/' || x == '^'};
    assert("Syntax Error!!" && b);
    return x;
}

double calculate(int x)
{
    char op{getOperatorInput()};
    double tmp{getDoubleInput()};
    if(op == '+')
    {
        return x + tmp;
    }
    else if(op == '-')
    {
        return x - tmp;
    }
    else if(op == '*')
    {
        return x * tmp;
    }
    else if(op == '/')
    {
        return x / tmp;
    }
    return 0;
}

void calculator()
{
    std::cout << "Enter your expression : ";
    double result{};
    int loopCount{0};
    do{
            if(loopCount == 0)
                result = getDoubleInput();
            result = calculate(result);
            loopCount++;
    }
    while(std::cin.peek() != '\n'); //LIKE THIS
    std::cout << "Your result is : " << result << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Are you speaking of the line `while(std::cin.peek() != '\n');` ??

Comment: You are depending on well defined behaviour. That *in itself* is not bad.

Comment: @RSahu Yes! absolutely

Comment: @MichaelD.Blake, you should make that clear in your post.

Comment: Rethink `assert("Syntax Error!!" && !std::cin.fail())`. Consult [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) and talk it through with your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) if you have to.

Comment: @RSahu I don't know how to put it. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: @user4581301 what is wrong about that ? `assert( "some message" && some_condition)` is a rather common pattern to have `some message` printed when the `assert` fires. Do I miss something?

Comment: @MichaelD.Blake, there is a link to [edit] your post.

Comment: @user463035818 Never seen it before. It looked damn peculiar to me, so I figured the user wanted some sort of magic to happen. Didn't occur to me that it would be a simple way to emit a message.

Comment: @user4581301 it is some sort of magic, though a rather harmless one

Comment: @user4581301 Plese bear with my `assert`, this program isn't meant for releasing.

Comment: No worries. Fault's with me on that one. I was worried you expected something unusual and magical to happen.

Comment: you just "realeased" it on a platform with loads of readers :P Note that it is always best to remove as much as possible from your [mcve], because anything not directly related to the question might just distract from it, but I really wouldnt complain about it

Comment: One thing though, asserting over bad user input is generally a bad idea. Humans suck at data input. Their meaty appendages are constantly smacking the wrong buttons on their primitive input devices. This is one of the reasons that iostreams don't default to throwing exceptions

Comment: Overshot a bit on that last edit. You just lost the complete part. Finding minimal AND complete while still being verifiable is tricky, but when you pull it off you have nothing but bug in the program and at that point you usually spot the bug on your own. That's the real reason a MCVE is recommended. If you MCVE first, odds are good you won't need the question.